# SQL Server 2008 - Script to Insert Rows of Records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new to using SQL Server. I have this list of users id and emails and would like to insert into a table userEmail

```
userEmail(emp_no, emp_email)
emp_no is the primary key
```

The insert statement would be

insert into userEmail (emp_no, emp_email) values ('12345', 'aaa@email.com')

I heard that there's a way to create a script that would be able to run more than one insert statements but I'm not sure how to do it and execute the script.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO userEmail (emp_no, emp_email) VALUES
('12345', 'aaa@email.com'), 
('45678', 'bbb@email.com'), 
('56788', 'ccc@email.com') etc
```

Max is 1000 via one insert statememt.

If you can place this list in a something like a CSV (Comma delimited) file, they you could just import it using the **Import Data** task in Management Studio (Right click on Database > Tasks > Import Data > Data source = Flat File Source etc... )

Comment: Thank you! I thought have to repeat the insert many times. Thank you so much.